# How to stop Chrome Omnibox search autocomplete?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

How do I turn off Chrome Omnibox auto-complete in the Omnibox? I am very annoyed at the slowness of this feature.

Comment: i have edited question and made it like q and a format

Comment: related https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=531241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you turn it off:

1. Select Customize( the three vertical lines icon ).
2. Select "Settings"
3. In the 'search' section set:
   *"Set which search engine is used when searching from the omnibox."* to **'NONE'.**

Comment: Does that allow you to still search directly from the omnibar...?

Answer (score 0):

My list of search engines does not have a `NONE` option as described in the accepted answer. However, I managed to turn off auto-complete by clearing the browsing history (under `Settings > Advanced > Privacy`). This will require me to clear it every few days, I expect.